# Simple Emgucv webcam feed appears to be memory leaking

Tags: vb.net, opencv, memory-leaks, emgucv

Following code is the method with which I retrieve frames from a webcam in a bigger project of mine:

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.CvEnum
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Imports Emgu.CV.UI
Imports Emgu.CV.Util

Public Class Form1

    Dim img As Mat
    Dim cam As VideoCapture

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Try
            cam = New VideoCapture(0)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'show error via message box
            MessageBox.Show("unable To read from webcam, error: " + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
                                "Try another")
            Return
        End Try

        AddHandler Application.Idle, New EventHandler(AddressOf Me.ProcessFrame)

    End Sub

    Sub ProcessFrame(sender As Object, arg As EventArgs)

        img = cam.QueryFrame()
        ImageBox1.Image = img

    End Sub

End Class
```

Basically it grabs a frame from the webcam and inserts it into an imagebox on the form. When running the code my memory consumption looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCbU6.png

What I gather from this is that something is not being properly disposed, but I can't figure out what it is. The more MP the webcam has the higher the memory spike. Same thing when loading local video files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Mat` class](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm) implements `IDisposable`. Calling `Dispose()` on the old image before showing the new one might help minimize the spikes, but as Lucas K mentioned not everything is guaranteed to be fully released until the GC runs.

```
img = cam.QueryFrame()

'Dispose of the old image (if one exists).
If ImageBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then ImageBox1.Image.Dispose()

ImageBox1.Image = img
```

In general you should call `Dispose()` on all classes that implement `IDisposable` when you're done using them (or wrap them in [`Using` blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement), where applicable).

Comment: Thanks! The memory usage line is pretty much flat now.

Comment: @observer : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!

Comment: @VisualVincent, Hi, I tried your solution, But the following exception is thrown: "System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.' "

Comment: @AchuthaperumalRK : Hello! Sorry for not seeing your comment, I haven't been on Stack Overflow for a while now. Unfortunately that kind of error is extremely hard to diagnose and is mostly thrown when working with unmanaged code (which EmguCV does). You might be doing something wrong or out of order, but it could also be the library itself that isn't properly coded and breaks in a certain situation.

Comment: @AchuthaperumalRK : I'm afraid the only troubleshooting tips I can give you is to set up a new project with only the most basic code and see if the error still occurs. If not, add more and more of your code and try to pinpoint the specific difference that causes it to break. If you can't find a solution post a question here and describe the steps you took.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the linked image the memory consumption is only reduced by the garbage collector (GC), which is executed based on fixed time cycles (therefore the oscillation).
Your code enters ProcessFrame() without releasing the capture device. I suggest the usage of [VideoCapture].release() as detailed [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html) to solve the problem. If you need a consistent framerate there is no way to avoid these memory spikes.

Comment: Releasing the videocapture will close it (the camera stream). You don't want to do that. The videocapture is initialized once and queried repeatedly to get frames till you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Reading frames is one of the slowest parts of video processing. Your minimum example isn't sufficient to help with the memory leak (if one really exists). Make sure you aren't creating the videocapture object repeatedly in a loop.